# Audio duration returns NaN

Tags: javascript, audio, nan

Accessing an HTML5 audio element (a .ogg file) with JavaScript in Chrome. The file does play properly, yet somehow it will not recognize the duration.

I just cribbed this code: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_audio_duration.asp (I know w3schools isn't great, but it seems like something else is the problem...)

```
var x = document.getElementById("testTone").duration;
console.log("duration:"+x);  // duration:NaN

var y = document.getElementById("testTone");
y.play();   // works!
```

the element...

```
<audio controls id="testTone">
    <source src="autoharp/tone0.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: what does your `html` look like?

Comment: because `audio` need time to load and it is not ready when you calling `.duration`

Comment: @Aravind added above...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add [`preload="metadata"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#attr-preload) to your tag to have it request the metadata for your audio object:

```
<audio controls id="testTone" preload="metadata">
    <source src="autoharp/tone0.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

In your code, attach an event handler, to set the duration when the [metadata has been loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata):

```
var au = document.getElementById("testTone");
au.onloadedmetadata = function() {
    console.log(au.duration)
};
```

Comment: REF: https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/

`preload='metadata'
“Hints to the UA that the user is not expected to need the video, but that fetching its metadata (dimensions, first frame, track list, duration, and so on) is desirable.”`

Comment: Thank you! I am still studying this, it helps. Page loading clearly has complexities that I need to understand better. A question: after the comment that the audio needed time to load, I tried wrapping my original code with a (jQuery) document.ready function... didn't work. Can you explain why not?

Comment: Also - why the use of a function here? It works, but I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Beside @FrankerZ's solution, you could also do the following:

```html
<audio controls id="testTone">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("testTone").duration;
    console.log("duration:" + x); // duration:NaN

    var y = document.getElementById("testTone");
    y.play(); // works!
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Is this an obscure way of explaining the problem with w3schools? A direct approach would be better...

Comment: @GregoryTippett in your code, the source is not valid as well.

Comment: @GregoryTippett `preload='metadata'` is a btter approch TBO :D

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..hope it will work i used this in 'timeupdate' event as i was getting same NaN error.

```
var x = document.getElementById("testTone").duration;
if(x){
    console.log("duration:"+x);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getDuration(){
let au = document.createElement('audio'), inp = document.getElementById('UploadInput');
  if (inp.value) {
    if (inp.files[0].type.match(/audio|video/g)) {
      au.src = URL.createObjectURL(inp.files[0])
      au.setAttribute('preload', "metadata")
      au.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', () => {
        console.log(`Duration: ~ ${au.duration.toFixed()}s`)
      })
      // document.body.appendChild(au)
    } else {
      console.log('File is not Audio/Video');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('No File Dropped!');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id=UploadInput type=file onchange="getDuration();">
```